# Is it possible to take a void as argument in processing

Tags: function, processing

I am making a button class and I would like it to take a void as an argument(in the constroctor) so that the void gets called when the user clicks it. So that I don't have to `void mouseClicked() {if (button.mouseIsIn()) {doIt();}` and it automatically gets called when the user clicks it. Like `Button button = new Button(x,y,width,height,handleMouseClick());`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: The title says processing(JAVA)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there's no such thing as "a void" - you can have a **function** with a **void return type**, but it doesn't make sense to call them **voids**.

That being said, this depends on whether you're using Java or JavaScript mode. Assuming you're using Java mode, then the answer is **no**, you can't pass functions as parameters. What you can do instead is pass an instance of a class, and then call the functions of that class. Something like this:

```java
class MyAction{
   void doIt(){
      //whatever
   }
}
```

Once you have this class defined, you can create an instance of it using the `new` keyword:

```java
MyAction myAction = new MyAction();
```

Which you can then pass into your `Button` constructor:

```java
Button button = new Button(x, y, width, height, myAction);
```

Then in your `Button` class, you can simply call `myAction.doIt()` whenever you want to call the function:

```java
void mouseClicked() {
   if (button.mouseIsIn()) {
      myAction.doIt();
   }
}
```

You can combine this approach with **anonymous inner classes** to allow you to create `MyAction` instances on the fly with their own implementation of `doIt()`. Something like this:

```java
MyAction actionOne = new MyAction(){
   void doIt(){
      doThingOne();
   }
}
Button buttonOne = new Button(1, 2, 3, 4, actionOne);

MyAction actionTwo = new MyAction(){
   void doIt(){
      doThingTwo();
   }
}
Button buttonTwo = new Button(1, 2, 3, 4, actionTwo);
```

If you're using JavaScript mode, then you can just pass functions as arguments directly.

More info can be found by googling "Java pass function as parameter" or "JavaScript pass function as parameter".

Comment: Thank you. This filled up the only void in my button class.

Comment: @Programmingcoder It's not called a void. It's called a **function**.

Comment: But that gives me error the function 'doIt()' does not exist

Comment: I meant the english 'void'

Comment: @Programmingcoder I understand what you mean, I'm just telling you that there is no such thing as "a void" - they're called **functions** with **void return types**. If you have a follow up question, please post a [mcve] (note: this should **not** be your entire project) in a new question.